# __init__ not being called for double inherited class

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
from form_utils import forms as betterforms
from django.db import models

class FilterForm(betterforms.BetterForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('filter form __init__')

    ...

class NewEntityForm(FilterForm, FileFormMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewEntityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # super(FileFormMixin, self).__init__() <-- really does not matter
        print('newentityform __init__')
```

FileForMixin defined as follows:

```
class FileFormMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileFormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('file form mixin __init__')
```

`FileFormMixin` is provided by https://github.com/mbraak/django-file-form, betterforms by https://github.com/carljm/django-form-utils.

The problem is, `FileFormMixin`'s `__init__` is never getting called. How can I fix that? I really need all of them. Right now it's executing only `FilterForm` and `NewEntityForm` constructors.

**UPDATE**

So, I looked at all mentioned classes `__init__`'s, and they're calling super()!

`FileFormMixin`:

```
class FileFormMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileFormMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`BetterForm`:

```
class BetterBaseForm(object):
    ...
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._fieldsets = deepcopy(self.base_fieldsets)
        self._row_attrs = deepcopy(self.base_row_attrs)
        self._fieldset_collection = None
        super(BetterBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BetterForm(with_metaclass(BetterFormMetaclass, BetterBaseForm),
                 forms.Form):
    __doc__ = BetterBaseForm.__doc__
```

More of that, printing class' mro as @elwin-arens proposed, gives following output:

`filter form __init__
NewEntityForm.__mro__ (<class 'myapp.forms.NewEntityForm'>, <class 'myapp.forms.FilterForm'>, <class 'form_utils.forms.BetterForm'>, <class 'django.forms.widgets.NewBase'>, <class 'form_utils.forms.BetterBaseForm'>, <class 'django.forms.forms.Form'>, <class 'django.forms.forms.BaseForm'>, <class 'django_file_form.forms.FileFormMixin'>, <class 'object'>)
newsiteform __init__`

But `__init__` for FileFormMixin is executed only if I call it explicitly as @tom-karzes advised

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably, BetterForm does not call super, so the chain stops there.

The only thing you can do is to swap the order of classes in the declaration:

```
class NewEntityForm(FileFormMixin, FilterForm):
```

Although of course this might affect any other methods that are defined in both classes.

Comment: Maybe add, why the order swap to change MRO is without alterantive - as pointed out, it may cause other problems. I understand,  this is because the betterforms module not calling the super method in the mixed in class initializer is not expected to be changesble (thirdparty code), right?

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr**

From your posted MRO of `NewEntityForm` you see the class `BaseForm`. [In the source of django.forms.forms.BaseForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ec6121693f112ae33b653b4364e812722d2eb567/django/forms/forms.py#L72-98) you can also see that this class does not call `super(BaseForm, self).__init__()` and therefore is responsible for breaking the chain to FileFormMixin.

In this case you can work around this by changing the order of NewEntityForm's base classes like so:

```
class NewEntityForm(FileFormMixin, FilterForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewEntityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Explanation**

What you're probably thinking is that the classes `FilterForm` and `FileFormMixin` exists as base classes side-by-side.

In reality inheriting from multiple classes creates a Method Resolution Order (MRO) that is a list of classes that is traversed linear, in-order. This order determines what `super` means in a given context.

A simplified example to demonstrate:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__()
    print('A', A.__mro__)

class B(object):
  def __init__(self):
    super(B, self).__init__()
    print('B', B.__mro__)

class C(B, A):
  def __init__(self):
    super(C, self).__init__()
    print('C', C.__mro__)


c = C()
```

`super` takes a class and moves one to the right in the method resolution order. So `super(C, self).__init__()` calls `B.__init__`, which should be obvious, but `super(B, self).__init__()` in this context calls `A.__init__` and not `object.__init__`, which probably is less obvious.

This is because in the above code example C has the following `method resolution order`:

```
C (<class 'C'>, <class 'B'>, <class 'A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

To put it in pictures, the left if what you might expect, the right is what's actually happening:

```
    Mental model             Actual model
        C                        C
        |                        |
       / \                       B
      B   A                      |
      |   |                      A
       \ /                       |   
      object                   object
```

So if B doesn't call it's super:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__()
    print('A')

class B(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print('B')

class C(B, A):
  def __init__(self):
    super(C, self).__init__()
    print('C')


c = C()
```

This results in A's `__init__()` not being called after calling `super(C, self).__init__()`.

This then begs the question what the MRO of `NewEntityForm` looks like. You can print the mro like so:

```
print('NewEntityForm.__mro__', NewEntityForm.__mro__)
```

This will probably show a list where `FileFormMixin` comes after a class that does not call it's super init method, as Daniel Roseman already said.

A possible solution might be to explicitly call the init of the class you want to apply like so:

```
class NewEntityForm(FilterForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewEntityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        FileFormMixin.__init__(self)
        print('newentityform __init__')
```

Or you could flip the base classes of `NewEntityForm` around.

Comment: `BaseForm` does not call it's super. A super in BaseForm for the MRO you added should trigger FileFormMixin `__init__`. But if any of the classes __before__  FileFormMixin do not call super init, then the chain breaks.  https://github.com/django/django/blob/ec6121693f112ae33b653b4364e812722d2eb567/django/forms/forms.py#L72-98

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the parent classes explicitly when invoking their `__init__` methods.  For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

class Baz(Foo, Bar):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Foo.__init__(self, x)
        Bar.__init__(self, y)
```